# Same data send two different table at a time by cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two different table one is customer another is users.In all field between customer and users two field are common 1)username 2)password.

When I will add data in customer this two field need to save at a time in two tables.I am able to save all customer table data.Here customer and users have   belongsTo relation.

Here is my Customer model :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Here is my customer controller add method

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Customer->create();
            if ($this->Customer->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer has been saved'), 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_fail');
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Customer->User->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

Here is my two view field

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class'=>'input-large'));
                            echo $this->Form->error('password'); ?>                 


<?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class'=>'input-large'));
                          echo $this->Form->error('firstname'); ?>
```

There is my user controller add methods

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $this->request->data['User']['user_type_id'] = $this->request->data['User']['role'];
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'), 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_fail');
        }
    }
    $roles = array('1' => 'Admin', '2'=> 'CallCenter', '6'=> 'Accounts');
    $this->set(compact('roles'));
}
```

How can I send this two data in users table ?May anybody help me please ?

Comment: when you create a new customer you need to create a new user too? And you have to set the same username and password both in users and customers table? And when you update a customer you have to update the user too? Please tell me if I understand well (and then please explain why you are doing such a complicate thing)

Comment: yes you are right when customer created that means customer is an user now.I have a customer registration from here user from is different,so here I need to add this data from customer to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may there is bad database design I know it.I need the specific solution on my question.My question was How can I send this two data in users table,So let ans

Here I made an object in customer controller

```
$this->Customer->create();
```

than I take this value from customer from users.Here is the code

```
$this->request->data['User']['username']=$this->request->data['Customer']['username'];
$this->request->data['User']['password']=$this->request->data['Customer']['password'];
```

Than I save this value across an id

Here the code

```
$this->request->data['User']['user_type_id']=2;
```

Than I save this data for users table

```
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

Now data have saved here is the output :

[image]

It may my knowledge is limited buy after try I have solved it.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, shoud work but I did not tried it.

see the [Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) about how to save associated models

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Customer->create();
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $data['User'] = array(
            'username' => $data['Customer']['username'],
            'password' => $data['Customer']['password'],
        );
        if ($this->Customer->saveAssociated($data)) {
            // your code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad database design, it's not normalized plus it requires you to duplicate code. Fix the base problem by having *ONE* users table and associate the customer profile with the user record as needed if the person who registers is a customer.